# Multiple certs with one private key on apache?

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

Really fundamental question here, but nothing a quick google search is lending itself to.  Do I need to generate a separate private key for each cert I use in apache?

Server details:

```
% /usr/sbin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.8 (Unix)
Server built:   Jan 24 2008 10:44:19
% uname -a
Linux ***.com 2.6.23.15-80.fc7 #1 SMP Sun Feb 10 17:29:10 EST 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
% cat /proc/versionversion 2.6.23.15-80.fc7 (mockbuild@xenbuilder4.fedora.phx.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20070925 (Red Hat 4.1.2-27)) #1 SMP Sun Feb 10 17:29:10 EST 2008
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, every certificate is a Public Key paired with a matching Private Key.

The Public and Private key portions of the certificate work together.

So yes, every cert has a separate private key.

Comment: Clear and concise -- thank you very much!